# How to highlight continent

Tags: jqvmap

I have to show statistics on a continent level (Europe, Asia, etc.).

How can I pass the data? I can find only samples to pass the data on a country level like:

```html
var sample_data0 = { "de": "10000", "at": "15000", "pl": "5000" };
```

I would like something like:

```html
var sample_continent-data = { "Europe": "10000", "Asia": "15000", "northamerica": "5000" };
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here's an answer for you....

Replace the code in your jquery.vmap.world.js file with this file (make a back up of your original):
http://www.filedropper.com/jqueryvmapworld
(There's too much data to paste it here - hence the link to a file.)

This will give you a map with continents rather than countries.

Then replace the code in jquery.vmap.sampledata.js with:

```
var sample_data = { "AF": "152.23", "NA": "11.58", "OC": "158.97", "AS": "85.81", "EU": "1.1", "SA": "351.02" };
```

That should just work now (assuming you had the basic maps working) - comment if anything has gone wrong, or the linked file has disappeared.

Comment: Ah... filedropper has, yes, "dropped", the file. Any chance it's still around somewere? Really wanted this myself.

Comment: I *might* have this file on a laptop at home - I will check for you but it won't be until later

Comment: Lovely. There's no hurry!

Comment: @elgholm here is a link to the world file. Using the sample data about you will have continents: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlXqk0_rwKDsgb9TnRv0TNd66fAQcA

Comment: Thank you so much!
Now, the client has dribbled the ball once again, the "regions" they want is neither continents or countries, it's a mix. So I will have to somehow merge the continents but "remove" holes in it for some countries, that are supposed to be it's own "region". OMG. I love my life! But this helps a lot! Thank you so much!

Comment: uh, sorry, maybe I'm stupid, but that data was the countries, not continents. What am I missing?

Comment: The file contains the country data but the sample data above is what you need for continents. The sample data gets what is needs from the countries.

Comment: I think I might not have made myself understood. Sorry for that. I wanted a map with the continents. Nevermind. We'll make our own map now instead, from SVG files. No worries!